# Java ArrayList Object Getting Old Values

Tags: java, tomcat, arraylist, tomcat7

When I run the my application scenario my `ArrayList<String> dataVal` getting the old values means they showing me some different values in variable new values + the values from last session. I am using the below code, I did put only required source code, not the all source code. So please verify my below code and confirm to me what is going wrong in my source code, that is deployed on `Tomcat 7`.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import com.novell.nxpe.NxpeCondition;
import com.novell.nxpe.NxpeException;
import com.novell.nxpe.NxpeInformationContext;
import com.novell.nxpe.NxpeResponseContext;
import com.novell.nxpe.NxpeResult;

public class PolicyConditionExtnTemplate implements NxpeCondition {
    ArrayList<String> dataVal = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public NxpeResult evaluate(NxpeInformationContext informationContext, NxpeResponseContext responseContext)
            throws NxpeException {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date dt = new Date();
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Canada/Eastern"));
        String currentTime = formatter.format(dt);
        System.out.println("PolicyConditionExtnTemplate : Date Time : " + currentTime);
        NxpeResult res = NxpeResult.ConditionFalse;
        System.out.println("dataVal : " + dataVal);
        res = NxpeResult.ConditionTrue;
        return res;
    }
    private void get_dataVal(DirContext eDirConn, Attributes att) {
        try {
            //dataVal.clear();
            for (Enumeration<?> vals = att.get("descriptionVal").getAll(); vals.hasMoreElements();) {
                String val = (String) vals.nextElement();
                System.out.println("get_dataVal AD_dataVal : " + val);
                if (val != null && !val.isEmpty()) {
                    dataVal.add(val);
                }
                System.out.println("get_dataVal dataVal : " + dataVal);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception inside get_dataVal : " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

I also put some sysout for verifying the values and I can see in the log, it showing me old values in the below sysout

```
System.out.println("dataVal : " + dataVal);
```

And If I am using the below code which I commented in the above source code, its working fine for me, but I want to know the reason why it's happening because there is no other reference of this particular variable where they can increase their values.

```
dataVal.clear();
```

I am using Java 1.8.0_121.

Comment: what do you mean by "old values"? also: if you compile with java 8, run it on java 8.

Comment: @Stultuske "Old Values" means they showing me some different values in variable new values + the values from last session.

Comment: Your method is private and never called. ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios I already mentioned that I did not put my full code, this method is called in some different method.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!